# How to update variable every minutes in Python?

Tags: python, email, heroku, host

I am trying to make a  python bot that sends COVID19 status to my email. But I didn't get email after I deploy it to Heroku. It's not AUTH_ERROR

```
from covid import Covid
Hello
import smtplib 
import time
from threading import Timer
import os 
covid = Covid()
email = "=myemail@gmail.com"
password = "mypassword"
server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com',465)
server.login(email,password)
server.sendmail(email,'mgkokooo2006@icloud.com',"Try")

def getdata():
    global mm,c,d,r
    mm = covid.get_status_by_country_id(28)
    c = mm['confirmed']
    d = mm['deaths']
    r = mm['recovered']
    time.sleep(5)
    global mm2,c2,d2,r2
    mm2 = covid.get_status_by_country_id(28)
    c2 = mm['confirmed']
    d2 = mm['deaths']
    r2 = mm['recovered']

 def run():
     getdata()
     if c2 > c:
     server.sendmail(email,'mgkokooo2006@icloud.com',
     f"""confirmed-{c2}
     deaths-{d2}
     recovered-{r2}
     New-Confirmed{c2-c}
     NewDeaths-{d2-d}
     NewRecoverd-{r2-r}
    """)
    Timer(60,run).start()

run()
```

Is there  a problem in getting data in variables?

Comment: What is the return value of `server.sendmail`?

Comment: I got an email from that message. The problem is that I don't get email when c2 > c

Comment: Are c2 & c strings or ints?  Note `'10' > '4' -> False`

Comment: They are ints .

Comment: The question "What is the return value of `server.sendmail`?"  It may return an error message, indicating that the server has rejected the message for some reason, or it may say that the message has been processed successfully, in which case the problem probably isn't in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is rather poorly formulated as the actual error message of the thrown expcetion is **missing**. Thus you're making it pretty hard for other developers here to help you out and we can merely **assume** what your issue might be.

An error I've run into a while ago when working with email automation, was not configuring the **Gmail Account Settings** accordingly. You need to grant access to **less secure applications** in your account's **security settings**.

If already done / this does not fix your error then please provide **further information**.